# Генератор статических страниц Django

Tags: html, python, django

Если есть сайт на `Python (Django)`, в котором страницы генерируются динамически, каким образом можно сгенерировать все возможные статические страницы, т.е., грубо говоря, скачать весь сайт со структурой и содержимым?

Answer (score 2):

Делается это веками проверенным способом.

Запускаем паука на главную страницу. Паук ищет все ссылки. Внешние ссылки (ведущие на другие сайты) пропускает. Переходит по каждой из этих ссылок. В полученной странице вновь ищет все ссылки. Если ссылку он уже получал, пропускает, если нет - переходит. И так до тех пор, пока ссылки не кончатся.

Правда, есть риск, что ссылки никогда не кончатся...

Comment: спасибо, точно, паук. по идее, если на сайте нет внешних ссылок, то когда-нибудь кончатся.

Comment: Да. Забыл добавить, что внешние ссылки надо игнорировать.